# Haskell recursive function to apply different functions to even and odd numbered index

Tags: haskell, recursion

I have been struggling with following problem for sometime. I spent many hours on the internet to find a viable algorithm in Haskell using recursive functions only but no success.

Define a recursive function funkyMap :: (a -> b) -> (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b] that takes as arguments two functions f and g and a list xs, and applies f to all elements at even positions ([0, 2..]) in xs and g to all elements at odd positions ([1, 3..]) in xs.

Example: funkyMap (+10) (+100) [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] = [(+10) 1, (+100) 2, (+10) 3, (+100) 4, (+10) 5].

To above problem, I attempted following solution, but HUGS give me compilation error "unification would give infinite type".

```
mapEven :: (a->a) -> [a] -> [a]
mapEven f [] = []
mapEven f (x:xs) = f x : mapOdd f xs

mapOdd :: (a->a) -> [a] -> [a]
mapOdd g [] = []
mapOdd g (x:xs) = x : mapEven g xs

funkyMap :: (a -> b) -> (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
funkyMap f g [] = []
funkyMap f g (x:xs) = (mapEven f x) ++ (mapOdd g xs)
```

Please suggest an alternate working solution.

Thanks

Comment: haskell is purely recursive

Comment: Just a hint: you could pass both functions to `mapEven, mapOdd` -- this is because you don't want to generate a plain `x` as you are doing in `mapOdd ... = x : ...`. Each `x` you generate should be applied to either `f` or `g`, according to whether it is found in an even or odd position. Once you have done that, you will not need `++`.

Comment: `funkyMap f0 g0 = snd . foldr (\a ((f,g),xs) -> ((g,f),f a:xs)) ((f0,g0),[])`

Comment: One requirement for the solution to pass is that it should use recursion.

Comment: Is the solution provided by user2407038 using recursion.
Please pardon my ignorance, I am a newbie to Haskell.

Comment: This sounds like a homework problem. Any kind of looping in Haskell uses recursion under the hood. Probably your instructor wants you to use explicit recursion, which the solution offered above does not use, the recursion is hidden inside standard higher level functions (`foldr`). BTW an even more compact solution (without explicit recursion) is: `funkyMap f g = zipWith ($) (cycle [f,g])`

Answer (score 2):

This line has a problem:

```
funkyMap f g (x:xs) = (mapEven f x) ++ (mapOdd g xs)
```

`x` is an element of the list (ie type `a`), while `xs` is another list (type `[a]`). But you are treating them the same. The error you are getting is because the only way to make sense of a list and an element being the same type is if it's a list of lists of lists of lists of lists...

Answer (score 1):

By God's mercy, I got some inspiration and I seemed to have cracked this problem.
Please review the following solution:

```
h1 p q [] = []
h1 p q ((cnt, val) : xs) = (if odd cnt then (q val) else (p val) ) : h1 p q xs

funkyMap f g xs = h1 f g ( zip [0..] xs)
```

If I try funkyMap (+10) (+100) [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] I get [11,102,13,104,15] which is expected.

Also funkyMap (+100) (+2) [1] gives
[101]

and funkyMap (+100) (+2) [] gives
[]

Please review this solution and let me know your feedback.

Thanks

Comment: While there are more elegant solutions, the above looks correct.